# Get Facebook list of friends in Titanium

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium

I'm trying to figure out how to get users friends list using Graph API in Titanium.

Something like

```
Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/friends', 'GET', function(e) {
...
});
```

But cant make it work

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/34758524584/alloy-listview-facebook-friends

Here you go the link of getting facebook friend list

Thanks